# Strange location of sub level list bullet

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a list of multiple nested unordered lists - up to seven nested lists. If the text of the list items breaks into two lines, the bullet is no longer vertically aligned. How can I fix this? [See example here](http://jsfiddle.net/5kr8qqjh/4/).

the issues are marked with red. I haven't been able to fix it using `:pseudo elements` either...

See image: [image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks perfectly okay...

Comment: I added an image to show you the issue.

Comment: I did. .-) But I would like the text to still wrap - right now it overflows the menu box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `<a>` tags inside the `<li>` tags to be `display: inline-block`. The default vertical-alignment of inline-block is `vertical-align: baseline`.

If you add this code it works

```
ul.sidebar-items li ul li ul li a {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5kr8qqjh/5/

---

#### addendum

You have no right control, over what you are doing, I guess.
At first you give the a tags a `display: table-cell` rule. I don't know, what you are trying to achive with this and the other `display: table` and `display: table-row` rules, but I think, they are not necessary. So drop all of them, and then you do not need the `display: inline-block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/5kr8qqjh/7/

Comment: It's much better, but the bullet is now vertically aligned to the top of the list items with the wrapping text. Isn't it possible to vertically align it to the center? I tried to change it to ul.sidebar-items li ul li ul li a {
  vertical-align: center; - but that didn't help.
}

Comment: It's middle, not center. center is for horizontal alignment

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right. Thanks for your help. I'll go with your vertical-align: top;

Answer (score 0):

That looks perfectly okay and it is what is expected. If you don't want them to go to bottom, use:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

So, here you go:

```
ul.sidebar-items > li a {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

And also you have missed some closing `</li>`s. Fixed everything here:

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uvk8aaLd/2/**

Comment: But I want the text to wrap - I just want the bullet to keep vertically aligned if the text breaks into two lines. I updated my question with an image. .-)

Comment: @Meek Try using `vertical-align: top` for the `<a>` tags.